# For Basis Change theorem, why use automorphisms?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm reading *Mathematics for Machine Learning* by Marc Peter Deisenroth, A. Aldo Faisal, and Cheng Soon Ong.

I have a question regarding a theorem presented in the book:

**Theorem 2.20** (Basis Change) For a linear mapping $\phi : V \rightarrow W$, ordered bases

$$B = (b_1,...,b_n), B'=(b'_{1},...,b'_{n})$$

of $V$ and

$$C = (c_1,...,c_n), C'=(c'_{1},...,c'_{n})$$

of $W$, and a transformation matrix $A_{\phi}$ of $\phi$ with respect to $B$ and $C$, the corresponding transformation matrix $A'_{\phi}$ with respect to the bases $B'$ and $C'$ is given as

$$A'_{\phi} =T^{−1}A_{\phi}S$$

Here, $S ∈ R^{n×n}$ is the transformation matrix of $id_V$ that maps coordinates with respect to $B'$ onto coordinates with respect to $B$, and $T ∈ R^{m×m}$ is the transformation matrix of $id_W$ that maps coordinates with respect to $C'$ onto coordinates with respect to $C$.

My question is regarding the transformation matrices $S$ and $T$:

Specifically, the authors define $S$ as the transformation matrix of a linear mapping $\psi_{BB'} : V \rightarrow V$ (automorphism) that represents B in terms of B'. Normally, $\psi = id_{V}$ is the identity mapping in V.

(T is defined similarly)

Why are $S$ and $T$ defined as automorphisms?

Comment: Huh?  The identity happens to be an automorphism.  A change of basis is basically just the identity linear transformation in disguise.  But not that much of a disguise, since it does take each vector to itself, just written in terms of a different basis.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand your question here, but it sounds like it's just the notation $\psi_{BB'}$ that's confusing you. You are indeed correct that $\psi_{BB'}$ should be $\operatorname{id}_V$, regardless of the bases $B$ and $B'$. The matrix $S$ should be defined as the matrix for the automorphism $\operatorname{id}_V$, from basis $B'$, to basis $B$.

Comment: @user837206 that's the point I was trying to make.  You just made it a little more clearly.